# Changing scope of dependency throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I have a class called `HelperFunction` which needs to be injected in a Razor-page using `(@inject)` and in doing so I'm using microsoft's built-in DI.

I'm using ASP.NET (.net5.0) and have setup my `Startup.cs` file like below:

```
public class Startup
{

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
  _ = services
      .AddScoped<HelperFunction>();
 }

 // UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
 public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
 {

  _ = builder.Register(ic => 
      {
       // Register Dependency1
      }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
  _ = builder.Register(ic => 
      {
       // Register Dependency2
      }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
  _ = builder.Register(ic => 
      {
       // Register Dependency3
      }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

  _ = builder.Register(ic => 
       new HelperFunction(
        ic.Resolve<Dependency1>(),
        ic.Resolve<Dependency2>(),
        ic.Resolve<Dependency3>())).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
 }
}
```

*When I run the program, the following error gets thrown:*

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Dependency1' while attempting to activate 'HelperFunction'. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)`

**When I modify the scope of the `HelperFunction` services from `Scoped` to `Singleton` the error isn't thrown and it works fine.**

While keeping the scope of the `HelperFunction` service to Scoped, I've registered it's dependencies `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()` and the error still shows up.

I find the need for `Autofac` here due to it's services like `Keyed`, `Named` etc., and the scope of `HelperFunction` needs to be `Scoped` since I need its creation to be on a per-request basis.